# Swig, convert c pointer to float[]

Tags: java, c, arrays, pointers, swig

I swig how do you convert the return value in c to a float[] in java

```
//C Function
inline float32* b2Body::GetWorldPoint(float32 localX, float32 localY)
{
    b2Vec2 val = b2Mul(m_xf, b2Vec2(localX, localY));
    fin[0] = val.x, val.y;
    fin[1] = val.y;
    return fin;
}
```

As you can see the function returns float32* which is a two element array. In my swig file I included

```
%include cpointer.i
%include "arrays_java.i"
%apply float[] {float32*};
```

But I get the error:

```
.cpp: In function '_jfloatArray* Java_com_google_fpl_liquidfun_liquidfunJNI_Body_1getWorldPoint_1_1SWIG_11(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jfloat, jfloat)':
C:/Users/Garrett/Desktop/liquidfun-master/liquidfun//Box2D/swig/jni/../gen/cpp/armeabi-v7a/liquidfun_wrap.cpp:6147:59: error: 'FillMeInAsSizeCannotBeDeterminedAutomatically' was not declared in this scope
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/liquidfun_jni/gen/cpp/armeabi-v7a/liquidfun_wrap.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Looks like it tells you that it needs to know the size of the returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same solution as [an older question on the mailing list](http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/how-can-I-return-an-array-who-s-size-is-not-static-td2511.html):

```
%include cpointer.i
%include "arrays_java.i"
%typemap(out) float[] 
%{$result = SWIG_JavaArrayOutFloat(jenv, (float *)$1, 2); %}
%apply float[] {float32*};
```

With a caveat that as written this will cause SWIG to assume that all `float*` usage as a return type is an array of size 2.